# python in memory cache

Tags: python, azure, caching, azure-functions

I am trying to achieve in memory cache for a python application azure functions

```py
/src
  /shared
    do_something.py
  /utils
    do_something_helper.py
  cache.py
  function_app.py
```

cache.py

```py
class InMemoryCache:
    cache: dict = {}

    def get_cache(key):
        try:
            return InMemoryCache.cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def set_cache(key, value):
        InMemoryCache.cache[key] = value
```

do_something_helper.py

```
from cache import InMemoryCache

def do_something_helper():
  blob_data = InMemoryCache.get_cache('blob_file_name')
  if blob_data:
    return blob_data

  blob_data = get_blob_data_from_storage()
  InMemoryCache.set_cache(key = 'blob_file_name', value = blob_data)
  return blob_data
```

do_something.py

```
from utils import do_something_helper

def do_something():
  # should be able to fetch from cache but always reading from blob
  blob_data = do_something_helper()
  process_blob_data()
```

function_app.py

```py
import azure.functions as func
from shared.do_something import do_something

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="hello")
@app.route('getBlobInfo',auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def get_blob_data(req):
  processed_data = do_something()
  return func.HttpResponse(body = processed_data, status_code = 200)
```

since azure functions app uses the same instance for multiple calls, The Aim is to reduce the number of calls to blob storage that improves performance.

expected behaviour: should be able to fetch from cache first
but always reading from blob.
I want this cache accessible globally for the whole project.

Am I doing Something wrong here?
reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#global-variables

edit : 2
here is the representation of get_blob_data_from_storage() , process_blob_data()

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
import json


def get_blob_data_from_storage(file_name):
    container_name = "data"
    BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "<connection string>"
    try:
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
            BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        raise Exception(e)

    if blob_service_client:
        try:
            blob_client: BlobClient = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
                container=container_name, blob=file_name
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            raise Exception(e)
        data = blob_client.download_blob()
        data1 = data.readall()
        return data1


def process_blob_data(blob_data):
    json_data = json.loads(blob_data)
    # match records based on request query
    return json.dumps(processed_json_data)
```

Comment: well, you never call `set_cache` anywhere, so I'm not sure why you expect the cache to ever cache anything.  Not exactly related, but your class definition is totally incorrect.

Comment: please share `function_app.py` file

Comment: added set_cache and function_app.py. this is just for reference as the actual code might contain some sensitive information.

Comment: Share the implementation of `get_blob_data_from_storage()` and `process_blob_data()`

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin 
**get_blob_data_from_storage()** collects a csv/json file from azure blob storage..
**process_blob_data()** reads the file and prepares a HTTPResponse body..
caching is not implemented in those methods yet.

Comment: Can you please share the codes for these methods

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code and it works without error but you need to incorporate a method to save the data in cache before using it.

**function_app.py**-

```py
import azure.functions as func
from src.shared.do_something import do_something

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="getBlobInfo")
def get_blob_data(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    processed_data = do_something()
    return func.HttpResponse(body = processed_data, status_code = 200)
```

**cache**-

```py
class InMemoryCache:
    cache: dict = {}

    @staticmethod
    def get_cache(key):
        return InMemoryCache.cache.get(key)

    @staticmethod
    def set_cache(key, value):
        InMemoryCache.cache[key] = value
```

**do_something**-

```py
from src.utils.do_something_helper import do_something_helper

def do_something():
  blob_data = do_something_helper()
  return blob_data
```

**do_something_helper**-

```py
from cache import InMemoryCache

def do_something_helper():
  blob_data = InMemoryCache.get_cache('blob_file_name')
  if blob_data:
    return blob_data
  InMemoryCache.set_cache(key = 'blob_file_name', value = blob_data)
  return blob_data
```

**Output**-

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use the below code to invoke an Api to get the Json response and then save it to in memory cache to use further.

```py
import azure.functions as func
import json
import requests

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Define an in-memory cache
    in_memory_cache = {}
 
    def fetch_data_from_endpoint():
        response = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
        return response.json()
    
    # Check if data is already in cache
    if 'cached_data' in in_memory_cache:
        # Retrieve data from cache
        data = in_memory_cache['cached_data']
    else:
        # Fetch data from endpoint
        data = fetch_data_from_endpoint()
        # Store data in cache
        in_memory_cache['cached_data'] = data
 
    # Convert data to JSON response
    response_data = json.dumps(data)
 
    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=response_data,
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
    )
```

Comment: yes, I already implement this solution. I am able to access cache on top level. I could not understand how can I be able access this cache in sub modules or in different packages.. appreciate your efforts.

Comment: my Initial works too.. somehow it didn't work as expected when last time I was testing. appreciate your efforts. thank you.